# Clojure thread-first macro (->) vs thread-last macro (->>) What are the practical differences?

Tags: clojure

I still do not fully understand the difference between the two Clojure arrow macros thread-first `->` and thread-last macro `->>`.
While reading through https://clojure.org/guides/threading_macros I understand that thread first -`>` is an alternative expression for nested operations on a single object, each datastep using the object as input argument, performing an independent operation.

```
(defn transformation [object]
  (transform2 (transform1 object)))
```

becomes

```
(defn transformation [object]
  (-> object
      (transform1)      ;; object as implicit argument
      (transform2)))    ;; object as implicit argument
```

When using threat-last `->>` operator, each tranformation uses output of the preceding transformation as implicit argument:

```
(defn transformation [object]
  (->> object
       (transform1)      ;; object as implicit argument
       (transform2)))    ;; (transform1 object) as implicit argument
```

What are the practical implicantions of these differences? I understand that it makes sense to use threat -first `->` for operations on maps and dictionaries, where each transformation creates a new copy of the original instance, which has to be supplied for the next operation.
However, in many cases, both operators actually behave the same:

```
(->> [2 5 4 1 3 6] (reverse) (rest) (sort) (count)) ;; => 5
(->  [2 5 4 1 3 6] (reverse) (rest) (sort) (count)) ;; => 5
```

Comment: Stuart Sierra has a post called threading with style that has good guidance on the usage of the threading macros.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does ->> mean in Clojure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41248466/what-does-mean-in-clojure)

Answer (score 5):

The practical difference is where the macro "inserts" the variable (and the subsequent results) into the expressions:

```clj
(ns so.example)

(defn example-1 [s]
  (-> s
      (str "foo")))

(defn example-2 [s]
  (->> s
      (str "foo")))

(example-1 "bar")
;=> "barfoo"

(example-2 "bar")
;=> "foobar"
```

So `(-> "bar" (str "foo"))` is the same as `(str "bar" "foo")` and `(->> "bar" (str "foo"))` is the same as `(str "foo" "bar")`. With unary functions `->` and `->>` do the same thing.

When you need more flexibility as to where these results should be inserted, you would use `as->`:

```clj
(ns so.example)

(defn example-3 [s]
  (as-> s v
      (str "foo" v "foo")))

(example-3 "bar")
;=> "foobarfoo"
```

Comment: Okay, the problem with my two examples behaving the same is they are just a nested chain of unary expressions: (count (sort (rest (reverse [2 5 4 1 3 6])))) ?

Comment: @GitCrush Yes I'd say so. But please do wait for other answers; there are very good Clojurists hanging out there and I don't compare with them at all ;)

Comment: @GitCrush or in other words: for single argument functions, the "first" and "last" argument for "threading first" and "-last" are the same argument position.

Comment: Just a note: as-> is intended to be used inside a -> chain, not standalone -- that's why its value argument is first and its name argument is second: (-> s (str "suffix") (as-> x (str "{" x "}"))

Comment: @SeanCorfield Thanks for the comment but I'm not sure I follow; the example I have with it seems to run perfectly. How can I make it better?

Comment: @customcommander Your example is too small/simple to really show why as-> exists. Your three example functions are really all too small/simple to even need -> or ->>. The idea behind as-> is that it can be used in the middle of a pipeline of functions being threaded by -> so that the value is placed at the first argument to as-> and you provide the symbol to bind that value to, just for that one slot in the pipeline where you either need the value in multiple places or in a non-first (or non-last) position. Hard to explain in a short comment but hopefully that clarifies the intended usage?

Comment: @SeanCorfield Ah I see. I intended the examples to be small, thought they'd be clear nonetheless. But yeah I see what you mean now, fair enough. Thx

Comment: @all thank you for the helpful input and discussion!

Answer (score 3):

Following up on `as->` as an answer purely because I can't format code in a comment.

Here's a usage of `as->` from our codebase at work:

```
                    (-> date
                        (.getTime)
                        (as-> millis
                          (/ (- (.getTime (java.util.Date.)) millis)
                             1000 60 60 24))
                        (long)
                        (min days))
```

That computation could be unrolled, and `->>` used to place the threaded value at the end of the `-` expression, but would probably be harder to read. It would also be possible to unroll it in such a way that `->` alone would be enough (by negating the threaded value and then adding it to `(.getTime (java.util.Date.))`) but that would make it even harder to read I think.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a misunderstanding on your part on how `->` works.

You say

> 1. `->` is an alternative expression for nested operations on a single object, each datastep using the object as input argument, performing an independent operation.

and then about `->>` you say

> 2. When using threat-last `->>` operator, each tranformation uses output of the preceding transformation as implicit argument

but statement 1 is not true, and statement 2 is true for both, `->` and `->>`.
This is very easy to test, like this:

```clj
cljs.user=> (-> [2 5 4 1 3 6] reverse rest)
(3 1 4 5 2)
cljs.user=> (-> [2 5 4 1 3 6] rest reverse) 
(6 3 1 4 5)
```

If you add `sort` to the end of the call chain, like in your example, you wouldn't notice this difference, because both results would be sorted.

Like `cfrik` said, when you are passing only one argument to a function, then the first argument and the last argument are the same (because there's just one), so that's why it's easy to get confused when all the functions in your call chain accept only one argument, which is the case with your example where you have used `count`, `sort`, `rest`, and `reverse`.

Another thing you might have missed from the documentation in https://clojure.org/guides/threading_macros is the fact that many functions that work with sequences, like `filter`, `map`, and `reduce`, take the sequence as the last argument as a convention, and that makes it possible to chain calls to them using `->>`, like

```clj
(->> (range 10) 
     (filter even?)
     (map #(+ 3 %))
     (reduce +))
```

which becomes

```clj
(reduce + (map #(+ 3 %) (filter even? (range 10))))
```

whereas `->` is more suitable for functions like `assoc` and `update`, which (like you said) work with single objects and take the object as their first argument (and "transformations/update" on that object as the rest of the arguments), so then you can do the following

```clj
(-> person
    (assoc :hair-color :gray)
    (update :age inc))
```

which becomes

```clj
    (update (assoc person :hair-color :gray) :age inc)
```

To better understand how macros work, try using `macroexpand-1`, like this

```clj
user> (macroexpand-1 '(->> (range 10) 
                      (filter even?)
                      (map #(+ 3 %))
                      (reduce +)))
(reduce + (map (fn* [p1__21582#] (+ 3 p1__21582#)) (filter even? (range 10))))
```

The argument `macroexpand-1` should be a quoted version of the function call, and the result will be the expanded function call.